# Storing credentials in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

When I try to create a a new snapshot in SQL Server Reporting Services 2005, i get the message: "report history may not be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored, the report is using user-defined parameter values, default report parameter values are missing, or if a linked report, the link is no longer valid"

Under Data Sources, it has "Windows integrated security" checked.  I can choose "Credentials securely stored in the report server" and enter my user name, password, but that doesnt seem right since I dont want to do that for every report.

Right now Im just running it on my local machine (http://localhost/Reports$SQL2005/), so I don't know why I would be getting these errors

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting a data source to use "credentials stored securely in the report server" is required when you want to use Reporting Services features like Subscriptions and Report Snapshots. You only have to do this on the data sources, so assuming you have not created a new data source for each and every report (and they are therefore sharing one or more data sources) you only have to set this up the first time you deploy the data source(s).

Many people create a specific domain account for Reporting Services and use these credentials for the data sources (making sure you have given the domain account necessary permissions to the underlying databases involved). This means that the reports are executed as the Reporting Services account whenever they are run.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160330(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Bit late on this post but I had an issue were I had the report Credentials stored in the report server but I still could not take a snap shot. turned the report had a sub report and I had to store the Credentials with that report as well to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with everything Nathan said.  Make sure the credentials you use have at least dbdatareader access to the reportserver, reportservertemp, and any other db's you use.